# How to append zero based on the length of the input type?

Tags: perl

I have multiple input lines in a file, and I want to search for a specific type in a line (search for Tr16 or Tr32). If the match is found, then I want to append zero with the corresponding value. But I want to ignore if the length of the value is greater than 3.

Ignore for these lines:

```
connect_next_frame  1234    Tr16, selection # since value is greater than >3

time_scheduler  76890    Tr32, selection  #  since value is greater than >3
```

Replace for these lines:

1. If its Tr16 or Sr16 then append the string value with zero

   ```
    { 0,  corresponding value}
   ```

for e.g.

```
    x317_dwsrp  { 0, 2 }    Tr16, selection
```

2. If its Tr32  then append with

   ```
    { 0, 0, 0, corresponding value }
   ```

for e.g.

```
    x315_conex  { 0, 0, 0, 1 }  Tr32, selection
```

My input lines:

```
x317_dwsrp  2   Tr16, selection 
x315           4     Tr16, selection        
user_info 20    Tr16, selection 
sib_pos    8   Sr16, selection  
dma_frame   1   Tr32, selection 
x315_conex  1   Tr32, selection
```

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $inputfile  = 'test_input.txt';
my $outputfile = 'test_output.txt';

open my $my_ipfh, "<", $inputfile or die $!;
open my $my_opfh, ">", $outputfile or die $!;

while (<$my_ipfh>)
{ 

if (/Tr16|Sr16|Tr32/)
{
 s/x317_dwsrp   (\d+)    Tr16, selection/x317_dwsrp  { 0, $1 }   Tr16, selection/g;
 s/x315     (\d+)    Tr16, selection/x315       { 0, $1 }    Tr16, selection/g;     
 s/user_info    (\d+)    Tr16, selection/user_info  { 0, $1 }    Tr16, selection/g; 
 s/sib_pos    (\d+)       Sr16, selection/sib_pos    { 0, $1 }      Sr16, selection/g;  
 s/tdma_frame   (\d+)   Tr32, selection/tdma_frame  { 0, 0, 0, $1 } Tr32, selection/g;
 s/x315_conex   (\d+)   Tr32, selection/x315_conex  { 0, 0, 0, $1 } Tr32, selection/g;  
}

 print $my_opfh $_;
}
```

My expected output:

```
x317_dwsrp   { 0, 2 }    Tr16, selection    
x315        { 0, 4 }     Tr16, selection        
user_info   { 0, 20 }    Tr16, selection    
sib_pos    { 0, 8 }      Sr16, selection    
tdma_frame  { 0, 0, 0, 1 }  Tr32, selection 
x315_conex  { 0, 0, 0, 1 }  Tr32, selection
```

Here I was doing based on replacement, but what could be optimized way?

Comment: When I edited your question I removed some leading whitespace. Since you also have tabulators in there, I am not sure if that whitespace might not  have been part of the input. Please [edit] and fix that if I accidentally broke it.

Comment: @toolic.. how keep the condition for below lines                                                  new_frame { 0, 499510 } Tr32, selection                          
sfn { 0, 0, 2765} Tr32, selection                              
offset { 0, 0, 312000} Tr32, selection Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the curly brackets in the replacement part, and there is no need for the `g` flag.

I've added a limit to 3 digits:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

while (<DATA>) { 
    chomp;
    s/(x317_dwsrp\s+)(\d{1,3})(\s+Tr16, selection)/$1\{ 0, $2 \}$3/;
    s/(x315\s+)(\d{1,3})(\s+Tr16, selection)/$1\{ 0, $2 \}$3/;
    s/(user_info\s+)(\d{1,3})(\s+Tr16, selection)/$1\{ 0, $2 \}$3/;
    s/(sib_pos\s+)(\d{1,3})(\s+Sr16, selection)/$1\{ 0, $2 \}$3/;
    s/(tdma_frame\s+)(\d{1,3})(\s+Tr32, selection)/$1\{ 0, 0, 0, $2 \}$3/g;
    s/(x315_conex\s+)(\d{1,3})(\s+Tr32, selection)/$1\{ 0, 0, 0, $2 \}$3/;
    say;
}


__DATA__
x317_dwsrp   2   Tr16, selection
x315        4     Tr16, selection        
user_info 20 Tr16, selection 
sib_pos    8   Sr16, selection   
tdma_frame    1   Tr32, selection 
x315_conex    1   Tr32, selection
```

**Output:**

```
x317_dwsrp   { 0, 2 }   Tr16, selection
x315        { 0, 4 }     Tr16, selection        
user_info { 0, 20 } Tr16, selection 
sib_pos    { 0, 8 }   Sr16, selection   
tdma_frame    { 0, 0, 0, 1 }   Tr32, selection 
x315_conex    { 0, 0, 0, 1 }   Tr32, selection
```

A more simple code:

```
while (<DATA>) { 
    chomp;
    s/(.+\s)(\d{1,3})(\s+[ST]r16, selection)/$1\{ 0, $2 \}$3/;
    s/(.+\s)(\d{1,3})(\s+Tr32, selection)/$1\{0, 0, 0, $2 \}$3/g;
    say;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more generalized way to reproduce your output:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<DATA>) {
    if (/(\d+)\s+[ST]r(16|32)/) {
        my $n = $1;
        my $r = $2;
        if (length $n < 4) {
            my $zeroes = ($r == 16) ? '0,' : '0, 0, 0,';
            s/(\s+)(\d+)(\s+)/$1\{ $zeroes $2 }$3/;
        }
    }
    print;
}

__DATA__
   x317_dwsrp   2   Tr16, selection 
   x315        4     Tr16, selection        
   user_info 20 Tr16, selection 
   sib_pos    8   Sr16, selection   
  tdma_frame    1   Tr32, selection 
  x315_conex    1   Tr32, selection
```

Comment: it woks.. just want to know i have Tr8 as well which is dont  want to match in [ST]r (\d+) what should be change ?Thanks